Editor View Broken After Updating to WordPress 6.6
I recently updated my WordPress site to version 6.6, and I've encountered a major issue with the editor view. The editor now looks like the image attached (that's exactly how it looks on top of the editor view, not scrolled), which is completely broken and unusable.
I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but none have worked so far: Cleared my browser cache and cookies, deactivated all potential plugins to rule out any conflicts.
Despite these attempts, the problem persists. Has anyone else encountered this issue after updating to WordPress 6.6? If so, how did you manage to fix it? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Can you please upgrade to latest version wordpress 6.6.1, after update also you faced the same issues, kindly roll back to the core version wordpress 6.4.5
i hope it will help you to solve this issue.

Answer 1: Yes, I have the same problem.
Answer 2: I have given up all hope and activated the Classic Editor plugin I had installed when encountering the Block Editor for the first time. I have updated my WP to WordPress 6.6.1; it does not resolve the unusable block editor interface issue. My post editor screenshot when classic editor is disabled.

In my situation, I simply left it alone without making any changes. And today, 3 days after the issue came up, I checked my editor view, everything appeared to be working perfectly. It looks like they resolved some issues with the new version. I hope your issue will get resolved as well!

I have the same issue, disabling Yoast SEO fixes the issue so it is a Yoast SEO plugin issue.
I have reported the issue to Yoast SEO.

I didn't change anything, just checked my editor view, and now everything looks great. In my case, it seems they fixed some issues related to the new version. I hope yours is fixed too!

I am facing the same issue. Initially I thought it was my theme/plugins. I tried by removing everything but still editor not working. Luckily it's my brand new site so I uninstalled WP 6.6.1 and reinstalled 6.5.5 and magic! its all good!! @wordpress team please look at this issue as critical.
